# Cannot change root access in MySQL to %

Tags: mysql, mysqli

This is a new MySQL Server install. I created my root password as part of the setup (on Centos 6.4).

When I connect to the server through a terminal, I can connect to MySQL and issue commands, using my root password.

select current_user;

gives me:

```
+----------------+
| current_user   |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
```

If I do:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxxx' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

I get:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

But when I do:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

Here's what I get:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*fdfgdgdggfggfgfg' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Am I not supposed to see another line for root@% in addition to root@localhost?

The real issue I'm having is that I can't connect to MySQL from outside of localhost (as in, I'm logged in using a terminal session), and if the MySQL server is not giving root universal access (root@%), then that would explain the problem.  When I try to connect using PHP (from my local MAC), the following is the returned MySQLi object:

```
mysqli Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 
    [client_info] => 
    [client_version] => 50008
    [connect_errno] => 2002
    [connect_error] => Connection refused
    [errno] => 
    [error] => 
    [field_count] => 
    [host_info] => 
    [info] => 
    [insert_id] => 
    [server_info] => 
    [server_version] => 
    [stat] => 
    [sqlstate] => 
    [protocol_version] => 
    [thread_id] => 
    [warning_count] => 
)
```

I realize that granting root access from % is not a great idea, but at this point, I'm trying to figure out why I can't connect to the MySQL server, and when I solve that, I will restrict access.

Answer (score 7):

`SHOW GRANTS` only gives you back whatever you are connected as, which was `root@localhost`.

`root@localhost` and `root@'%'` and completely different users. Just do

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR root@localhost;
SHOW GRANTS FOR root@'%';
```

- `root@localhost` lets you connect from the DB Server via mysql.sock (the socket file)
- `root@'%'` lets you connect via TCP/IP, but **you must explicitly connect with that protocol**. Otherwise, mysqld connects you as `root@localhost`. This is true even if you attempted to connect using `127.0.0.1`.

## SUGGESTION #1

For the sake of security, you should use netblocks instead of '%'. For example, if you web servers at 10.1.2.20, 10.1.2.30, and 10.1.2.40, you should create

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'10.1.2.%'
IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*fdfgdgdggfggfgfg' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

instead of having a remote root.

## SUGGESTION #2

If you really want the remote root, here is what you do

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET host='%'
WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

That will do what you want, but remote root is not recommended.

## SUGGESTION #3

Since `root@'%'` already exists, then remove the root@localhost.

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This will leave `root@'%'` as the only root user, but you must connect explicitly with TCP/IP.

Comment: Suggestion #2 produces the following error: ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '%-root' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Solution #2 worked for me. Thanks.